# Xiaomi Redmi Note 7S on LineageOS 20 auto-restarting

Tags: boot-loop, lineageos, xiaomi

My Xiaomi Redmi Note 7S is running on LineageOS 20, but it keeps restarting itself before it can boot.

Also, sometimes if it boots to LineageOS, touching the power button (not even pressing it), wakes it up, and opens the camera and other apps like it has an extra sensitive fingerprint sensor.

Comment: Could be a hardware or software problem. Try if the boot behavior changes while the phone is connected to a charger. If it changes it could be a bad battery. If not check logcat and try to get `last_kmsg` to see kernel messages.

Comment: Hi could you explain how to take these logs and where specifically should i see the kernel messages. I tried  "adb logcat  -d > logcat.txt"  without quotes but it made about a 4Mb text file. So how to execute command having  last_kmsg  in it to see the kernel logs

Comment: Please search this site for `last_kmsg` and you will get a lot of answers. Note that to my knowledge not all devices have a`last_kmsg`, so your device my or my not have it..